# UML notation for C++ Link Seam (shared header with different implementation)

Tags: c++, uml, cross-platform

In a C++ cross-platform library,
we use shared headers which are compiled with different module versions for each OS.
A.k.a Link-Seam

```
//Example:
//CommonHeader.h
#ifndef COMMON_HEADER_H
#define COMMON_HEADER_H
class MyClass {
public:
  void foo();
}
#endif
```

.

```
//WindowsModule.cpp
#include "CommonHeader.h"
void MyClass::foo() {
  //DO SOME WINDOWS API STUFF
  printf("This implements the Windows version\n");
}
```

.

```
//LinuxModule.cpp
#include "CommonHeader.h"
void MyClass::foo() {
  //DO SOME LINUX SPECIFIC STUFF HERE
  printf("This implements the Linux version\n");
}
```

Of course, in each build you only select one module, respective to the environment you are using.

This is meant to suppress the indirect call to the functions

**My Question is: How to note this relationship in UML ?**

"Inheritance"? "Dependency"? "Note"?

Comment: Interesting question. It is multiple implementations of the same interface, so it could be seen as inheritance from an interface, but programatically it isn't.

Comment: @user4581301 my main problem is that some implemnentations have other details then others. e.g. for windows, we have an associated com-channel, which is not there for Linux... therefore i really want to explicitly show the implementations in UML, and not just the header interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyClass {
public:
  void foo();
}
```

This is nothing more than a class contract, so basically an interface which you *realize* in different modules. To visualize that, you can use *interface realization* notation (like a generalization, but with dashed lines).

[image]

Comment: Humm, I think maybe to be an interface programmatically foo() would need to be declared as virtual and then you’d have two other classes inheriting from it. But I do get what you’re aiming for here!

Comment: i think this is what ill use with a note to emphasize the implementation.

Comment: @muszeo UML doesn't specify how exactly should various concepts be implemented, so you don't need to declare it as anything; the objective is communication between people. If you need precise semantics for a particular language, then you can use UML profile for that language.

Answer (score 1):

The reality is I think that you’ve got only one class in a UML class diagram, being MyClass, with a public operation foo(); it’s just that you have two code implementations of this class, one for Linux and one for Windows. UML Class models are not really setup to answer the question of how you implement this, in your case using c++ with header files: Imagine if instead you in-lined your functions and ended up writing two inline implementations of MyClass, one for Linux and one for Windows. Logically you still have one class in your class diagram (but with two implementations) and the header file (or lack thereof) wouldn’t come into it. What you need therefore is a way to show a how the C++ is structured, not a way to show the logical class constructs. I’m not aware of a specific way in UML to represent code structure, however you could build a code structure model using Artefacts maybe (?) which could denote the c++ file structures.

Comment: thats probobly the correct direction, though because i have details on each implementation, i wanted to show each. and i dont want to create new diagrams at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It could be seen as some kind of "inheritance". There is however no relation between classes as there is just one class - so there is no relation between two. The actual construct of using platform dependent implementation however imitate relation "is a".

Comment: But how would you note in a UML of the Library this construct ?
So a reader would be able to know how to extend the package with a , lets say, VxWorks implementation? or just understand the structure of the library

Comment: If I should just document the existing library, I would use Note as the Inheritance relationship may confuse the reader. The other possibility is to refactor the code, but I understand this may not be an option. Anyway I am really curious if there is any concrete UML notation for this kind of construct.